# Looking for Mindmap in OneNote

Tags: onenote

I am looking for mindmap in OneNote. There is one in http://www.onenotegem.com/onenote-mind-map.html, but I cannot find any recommendation to it.

Is it safe?
or
Any other candidate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are safe according to Microsoft and Kaspersky...

I personally use Gem and Batch [favorite one](http://www.onenotegem.com/document/onenote-open-a-folder-as-notebook)